# Проблемы с float

Tags: css, float

Есть форма. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при раскрытии описания форма растягивалась.
Пока я просто задал `margin`, чтобы текст не выползал за рамки.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
/*focus*/
/*placeholder*/

$("input").focus(function(){
 $(this).parent().children(".label").animate({"margin-top": "-20px"}, 300);
 $(this).animate({"padding-top": "0px"}, 300);
})

$("input").focusout(function(){
 $(this).parent().children(".label").animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 300);
 $(this).animate({"padding-top": "14px"}, 300);

});
/*animate description*/

$("#f-phone, #f-email").children("input").focus(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().children(".i-descr").slideDown();
});

$("#f-phone, #f-email").children("input").focusout(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().children(".i-descr").slideUp();
});

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One:400i');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans');

.sect-input select,.sect-input input:active, .sect-input input:focus {
 outline: none;
}

.container{
 padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.clr:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container{
 position: relative;
 width: 900px;
 min-height: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
.form{
 position: absolute;
 left: calc(50% - 250px);
 top: 70px;
 width: 530px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 200px;
 border-radius: 7px;
 background-color: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}

.f-header{
 font-family: 'Changa One', cursive;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #0072BC;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.f-close{
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -5px;
 right: 20px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background: url(http://myfrelance.ho.ua/images/f-close.png
) no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
 background-size: contain;
 display: inline-block;
}

.f-steps{
 position: relative;
 top: -6px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 200;
 color: #0072BC;
}
.f-step{
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 10px;
 width: 90px;
}
.f-step:first-child{
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.f-steps span{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 border: 1px solid #0072BC;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #fff;
}
span.step-active{
 background-color: #0072BC;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff,inset 0 0 2px #fff;
}

.f-content{
 padding: 24px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
.f-description{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 color: #949494;
}

.sect-input{
 position: relative;
 width: 230px;
 height: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 1px solid #949494;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.sect-input select{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border:none;
 background: none;
 appearance: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 -o-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-top: 19px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 color: #949494;
}

.sect-input input{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #949494;
 padding-top: 14px;
 padding-left: 9px;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.sect-input .label{
 padding: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 color: #0072BC;
 font-weight: bold;
 z-index: -1;
}

/* ARROW*/
.arrow{
 border-left: 1px solid #949494;
 position: absolute;
 height: 38px;
 top: 0px;
 right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 z-index: -1;
}
.arrow-down {
 margin-top: 16px;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 11px solid transparent;
 border-right: 11px solid transparent;
 border-top: 11px solid #0072BC;
}
.f-input-item{
 float: left;
 width: 230px;
}

.f-input-item:nth-of-type(even){
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.f-input-item:nth-child(2){
 float: none;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.i-descr{
 margin-top: 10px;
 color:#0072BC;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 1px;
 width: 100%;
 display: none;
}

.f-bottom-content{
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <div class="form clr">
  <div class="f-header">Contact form <div class="f-close"></div></div>
  <div class="f-steps">
    <div class="f-step"><span class="step-active"></span>You</div>
    <div class="f-step"><span></span>Outbound party</div>
    <div class="f-step"><span></span>Return party</div>
  </div>
  <div class="f-content clr">
   <div class="f-description">
    Description why is it needed, so the user feels encouraged, not discourages by the length of the step
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Title</div>
     <select name="Title" value="">
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="Mis">Mis</option>
     </select>
     <div class="arrow">
      <div class="arrow-down"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Name</div>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="e.g. John" value=""></input>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Surname</div>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="e.g. Doe" value=""></input>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Street</div>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="e.g. Baker Street 221B" value=""></input>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Postal code</div>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="e.g. 012345" value=""></input>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">City</div>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="e.g. Berlin" value=""></input>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Country</div>
     <select name="Title" value="">
      <option value="Mr">Germany</option>
      <option value="Mis">England</option>
     </select>
     <div class="arrow">
      <div class="arrow-down"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div id="f-phone" class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Mobile number</div>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="e.g. Berlin" value=""></input>
    </div>
    <div class="i-descr">Leave your phone number so we can contact you in a case of any ...</div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-input-item">
    <div id="f-email" class="sect-input">
     <div class="label">Email</div>
     <input type="email" name="" placeholder="e.g. john@doe.com" value=""></input>
    </div>
    <div class="i-descr">We will send you confirmation on this email.If you choose to register, your e-mail is your login.</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="f-bottom-content"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

С `clearfix` проблемы или с чем?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы надпись появилась, нужно нажать на поле "Mobile number" или "Email".

[Пример в CodePen](http://codepen.io/junior-web-dev/pen/apajmR).

Answer (score 0):

Текст находится внутри блока с `<input>`-ом, а ему задана фиксирована высота. Вот текст и не может тянуть фиксированную высоту.